# Not able to update NPM using CMD command

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to update my NPM using CMD command, But I end with this error:

```
D:\test1>npm update
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 407 http://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
```

How to fix this?

Comment: http://100pulse.com/http-statuscode/407.jsp 407 error = proxy authentication error

Comment: But I can visit all pages. I configured my npmrc file too.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824517/get-node-js-npm-command-to-work-behind-corporate-proxy

Comment: If you want to update npm to the latest version, run `npm install -g npm`. Not sure if this is what you are trying to do, though.