# nodejs module npm install error / gcm-node module send err

Tags: node.js, push, npm

my ubuntu12.0.4 server,
npm install error, please help me

---

https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm

---

```
$npm install node-gcm


npm install node-gcm
npm WARN package.json dateformat@1.0.6-1.2.3 No repository field.
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gcm
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gcm
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/node-gcm
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-virtual
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "node-gcm"
npm ERR! cwd /home/Tonight
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/Tonight/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

---

node-gcm send error > Exception during GCM request: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem with your connection to the Internet.  Can you try to install a different module like `npm install express` and also verify you are connected to the Internet with `ping stackoverflow.com`

You might also want to check that you are using recent versions of node and npm and even maybe reinstall if possible in case something is corrupted with your installation.

If you need to setup a proxy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996200/node-js-npm-proxy-and-node-modules) link details someone with a similar error and has a good explanation of how to solve it.

From the link above you could try:

`npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`

`npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`