# Cannot install socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io, virtualenv, ubuntu-13.10

I can't install socket.IO. It's in my virtualenv, if that matters. I am learning from a [blog](http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/) and I have installed till Node js. But I just can't install it in my Ubuntu VM. I get this error:

```
(chatn)robin@robin-VirtualBox:~/webs/chatn$ sudo npm install socket.io
npm http GET http://registry/socket.io
npm http GET http://registry/socket.io
npm http GET http://registry/socket.io
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm http 503 http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm http 503 http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-0.9.16.tgz
npm http GET http://registry/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET http://registry/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET http://registry/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET http://registry/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET http://registry/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET http://registry/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET http://registry/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET http://registry/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET http://registry/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET http://registry/base64id/0.1.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing redis@0.7.3
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /home/robin/webs/chatn
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm http GET http://registry/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET http://registry/policyfile/0.0.4
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/robin/webs/chatn/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I just don't know what's happening here.

**Update:**

Tried installing 'yeoman' but again got this message:

```
advenio@advenio-VirtualBox:~$ npm install -g yo
npm http GET http://registry/yo
npm http GET http://registry/yo
npm http GET http://registry/yo
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /home/advenio
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/advenio/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: are you unable to npm install any other modules? or the problem is only with socket.io?

Comment: No, I can't. I tried installing yeoman, but again I got the same type of message! I've updated my question with the message.

Comment: are you behind a proxy? have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996200/node-js-npm-proxy-and-node-modules

Comment: try change the registry: `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: to check what is the current registry: `npm config ls`

Comment: Also do not run `npm install` as sudo, when you install locally. Can you also post your package.json ?

Comment: @klode Hello! Thank you so much for your help! I don't know what happened, but after going through a lot of stuff, it worked!!!! Thank you again! :D