# Error with network connectivity when install Phonegap

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm trying to install phonegap with command:
npm install -g phonegap.
I get the following error:
 [image: phoneGap Installatation Error]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy (possibly doing this at work)?  If so, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996200/node-js-npm-proxy-and-node-modules

Comment: @dylants I have already tried: npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080 and
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080 , and it didn't help and i'm actually not at work

Comment: you should only add those specific strings if that is in fact your company's proxy address -- adding them outside of work would only make things worse.  Can you install any node packages?  Or have you ever been able to install a node package?  Can you browse to http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap ?

Comment: @dylants , I actually get the same error when i'm trying to install other package (like prompt) and got the same error

Comment: Can you open a browser and successfully browse to http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap

Comment: @dylants , yes the browser doesn't have any issues to browse  registry.npmjs.org/phonegap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55074/discussion-between-dylants-and-nir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your `.npmrc` file does not contain any unnecessary configuration.  An error like the one you have above states that you are unable to connect with the npm registry.  Sometimes that requires configuring a proxy, other times your configuration is just incorrect.  Look inside the `.npmrc` file (which is contained within your home directory -- `C:\Users\nir`) and verify the configuration settings are correct.  Delete any incorrect ones (proxy settings that are invalid, etc), or just rename the file and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have problems with connection.
I've it installed same way right now.