# Error while installing cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, cmd, phonegap-build

I was trying to install cordova in my PC. I am getting following error.

```
> Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.0 (x64) and npm.

    C:\Users\DELL>npm install -g cordova
    npm WARN engine npm@1.4.28: wanted: {"node":">=0.8","npm":"1"} (current: {"node"
    :"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
    npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.7.3: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
    0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
    npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
    "node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/resolve/-/resolve-0.7.1.tgz
    npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND p
    roxy.company.com
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/resolve/-/resolve-0.7.1.tgz
    npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND p
    roxy.company.com
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/resolve/-/resolve-0.7.1.tgz
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
    \\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
    npm ERR! node v0.12.0
    npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
    npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
    npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
    npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

    npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
    npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
    npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
    npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
    gs.
    npm ERR! network
    npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
    npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\npm-debug.log

    C:\Users\DELL>
```

Comment: Do you happen to be behind a proxy or did you configure npm to use "proxy.company.com"? Because that seems to be the cause of your issues here

Comment: yes  i configure npm to use  "proxy.company.com". Because when i searched for the error, there is a solution like to do so in a website. now how can i fix the problem?

Comment: i also try , 
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080   
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

From this link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996200/node-js-npm-proxy-and-node-modules

Answer (score 1):

Your installed node.js version is 0.12, uninstall the same and try to install 0.10.0 version of node.js. and then try to install the cordova.

Hope this will help...