# install express using npm install in windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting the following error. This is probably because I am behind a network proxy. Kindly tell me how to install the npm modules when one is behind a proxy.

```
D:\NodeMVA-master\NodeMVA-master\07_BasicExpress>npm install -g express
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\NodeMVA-master\NodeMVA-master\07_BasicExpress\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: `npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'`

Comment: You will find a ton of answers on stackoverflow how to use npm behind a proxy!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js, NPM, proxy and node\_modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996200/node-js-npm-proxy-and-node-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

HTTP proxy: `npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port`

HTTPS proxy: `npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`